# Unable to load file from internal storage into gallery

Tags: android, gallery

I have a little problem with my app. I have a function to take picture and store it then load it in the gallery.

Before storing the picture i check if the phone has an `ExternalStorage`. if not the picture is saved on Files directory with `getFilesDir()` but i can't load it on the gallery from internal storage.

code to load picture on gallery from `ExternalStorage`(rescan ExternalStorage, Work perfectly) :

```
 path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"";
 c.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"
                        + path)));
```

code to load picture on gallery from `Files`directory (doesn't load anything) :

```
 c.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"
                    + c.getFilesDir()+"/files/")));
```

PS: The file exists. I checked it with `adb shell`.

Comment: Are you just getting null after your load, or are you erroring out?

Comment: there is no error but i can't see the picture in the gallery

Comment: Can you display the code for how you display the image?

Comment: i don't display the picture programatically. I just **Force** the gallery to rescan the directory and it load it self the new pictures. the function is showed above.

Comment: Ok, this code doesn't say anything about the gallery. It just states that you are sending an Intent. You say that the broadcast works just fine, so this leads me to believe that the code that tells the gallery to display the images in wrong.

Comment: i won't show the gallery from my app. I want my picture to be added to my gallery. and the code above rescan my sdCard so it load the new pictures to my gallery. my question is : Can i do the same with internal storage.

Comment: Then my answer is: yes you can.

Comment: Can you please tell me how i can achieve that ? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, files saved in internal storage (application folder - /files) are only available for the application that created them - it's assured at filesystem level - and the Gallery app cannot load the file. When you save a new file in internal storage you must explicitly allow the file to be readable/writeable by other apps. Reference: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

"MODE_PRIVATE will create the file (or replace a file of the same name) and make it private to your application. Other modes available are: MODE_APPEND, MODE_WORLD_READABLE, and MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE."

Comment: This is a more correct answer, though there's a strong possibility that the gallery app may simply assume it cannot access the files in a different app's internal storage area, without checking to see if access has actually been granted.

Comment: The Gallery app doesn't need to "assume" anything :)
That's my working code snippet:

`String filePath = getApplication().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + fileName;
File f = new File(filePath);

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(f), "image/*");
startActivity(intent);`

Comment: Glad to hear it works.  Out of curiosity, can you manage to get the image added to the gallery's collection, or are you only able to get the gallery's viewer to show it on demand from your app?

Comment: It was the code intended for opening the image in Gallery viewer from my app.